# How to solve a failing VM start due to full boot disk?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, boot

Hi GCP users and Googlers,

I have the following issue with my user-managed VertexAI workbench :

1. I have made a mistake in my previous code, filling up the VM boot disk to full capacity.
2. Then I cannot start the Docker Application container after I start the VM.

The following logs show it:

> Dec 13 18:35:07 experiments-df-notebook systemd[1]: Starting Docker
> Application Container Engine...

> Dec 13 18:35:07 experiments-df-notebook google_metadata_script_runner[778]: Starting
> startup scripts (version 20211116.00).

> Dec 13 18:35:07experiments-df-notebook google_metadata_script_runner[778]: No
> startup scripts to run.

> Dec 13 18:35:07 experiments-df-notebook systemd[1]: google-startup-scripts.service: Succeeded. [[0;32m  OK
> [0m] Started [0;1;39mGoogle Compute Engine Startup Scripts[0m.

> Dec 13 18:35:07 experiments-df-notebook systemd[1]: Started Google Compute
> Engine Startup Scripts.

> Dec 13 18:35:08 experiments-df-notebook
> dockerd[849]: time="2021-12-13T18:35:08.691512023Z" level=info
> msg="Starting up"

> Dec 13 18:35:08 experiments-df-notebook dockerd[849]:
> failed to start daemon: Unable to get the TempDir under
> /var/lib/docker: mkdir /var/lib/docker/tmp: no space left on device

> Dec 13 18:35:08 experiments-df-notebook systemd[1]: docker.service:
> Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
> [[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start [0;1;39mDocker Application
> Container Engine[0m. See 'systemctl status docker.service' for
> details.

> Dec 13 18:35:08 experiments-df-notebook systemd[1]:
> docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

> Dec 13 18:35:08
> experiments-df-notebook systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application
> Container Engine. [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped [0;1;39mDocker
> Application Container Engine[0m.

I cannot even SSH the VM as expected. I would like to access the notebook to save it, in order not to loss the faulty code...

Is there any hope in this particular case?

Thanks

Best regards

Jerome

Comment: Go to the Google Cloud Console GUI. Select the persistent disk that the VM boots from and resize it larger. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-debian-9-resize-root-file-system/

Comment: Thanks John. It works. I have tried before to make an image of the full disk and to resize the image before to instantiate on another VM. But your solution is much much better. I am so angry against myself for not having found the solution by myself :). Thanks again.